# Android Fragment initialization

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am meeting with **Fragment** for the first time. So it is a bit complicated to me. I am reading a tutorial at [android-hive](http://androidhive.com). But I am unable to understand a point. There are something I don't understand. 
There are oneFragment(), twoFragment()... But I can't initiate them. So, please complete any of those... oneFragmemt() or twoFragment() from this [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/). I will be so pleased. Help me...

Comment: The first link is broken and I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I am sorry for the broken link. But see, second link and read the tutorial. You will understand then.

Comment: I know fragments well, so I don't want to read it completely. How do you try to initiate the fragments? Might be that gives me an idea about your problem.

Comment: My problem is at 2 no point when the tutor is adding fragments to the custom fragment adapter.

Comment: There `adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");`

Comment: You don't have to read the whole. Just read the 2 no point where the fragments are being added to custom adapter

Comment: Yes yes. Just complete oneFragment().

Comment: Here with my upvote you should be able to enter [this chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19132/java-and-android-era). I want to avoid to spam the comment section.

Comment: if you don't mind, you can answer this problem here (I think so). If u have solved my problem then post here and I will verify

Answer (score 1):

Muhamar, you always need to initiate the fragment inside an activity. If your fragment 1 has this code:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

    public OneFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
    }

}
```

then in the main activity you can initiate like in the tutorial says:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  //blabla

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //blablabla
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    //blabla
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

In this case the main activity is using an adapter to display more than one fragment, so you should have in your code more the file of the adapter, which you can find also in the tutorial.

**UPDATE:**

if you don't want to initalize the fragment with the adapter, you have to do two things to initialize the fragment:

**1) Put fragment in layout:** in the layout of your main activity you have to include a fragment and identify it (in  this example `android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"`):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment"
              android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**2) Insert the fragment in your main activity:** with the following code you can add the freagment in your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);



            OneFragment firstFragment = new OneFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.headlines_fragment, firstFragment).commit();

    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** to initialize from the adapter you just have to add it on the main activity, as the tutorial says. add this class on main activity:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: And here is my problem, initializing fragments into activity. I don't know how to initialize fragments into activity. Will you try?

Comment: And if I initialize fragrant into adapter then how I will do it?

Comment: when I write adapter.add (new OneFragment(), "First"); then it shows me RED_LINE error. I want to know here what is OneFragment() and where is OneFragment's code? Can you write that?

Comment: OneFragment is the fragment class, it's at the beggining of my answer

Comment: So, why I get error when I type that? I have no error here.